# Vb.net refactoring code re. locking/unlocking bitmapdata & repetitive pixel access

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, emgucv, bitmapdata

I am a beginning programmer in vb.net and c#, working on a slightly advanced project.
Within a class library used for image processing, I have defined a class for fast pixel access that converts 4 channels bitmap into a byte array of bitmap.width * bitmap.height * 4 size (class is reproduced in code section #1 bellow).
Then I take action on the byte array to change some pixel value (code section #2 bellow is a sample of it). That code is very repetitive but I am yet to find a way to make it more concise and systematic. I am thinking re-usability here. It is very fast though and I would like as much as possible not to change the approach. Emgu.CV.Image set pixel method and image.data method are both much slower for the same purpose. Also no filters in Emgu library can give me as much control over the change I want to effect.
Thanks for your time and ideas

Section1: Class definition

```
 Private Class BitmapBytesRGB32
            Public ImageBytes() As Byte
            Public RowSizeBytes As Integer
            Public Const bytesPerPixel As Integer = 4
            Private m_Bitmap As Bitmap ' Creates a new private bitmap for future operation
            Private m_BitmapData As BitmapData ' and a private bitmapData class
            Public total_size As Integer

            Public Sub New(ByVal bm As Bitmap) ' passes the bitmap ref inside our BitmapBytesRGB32 class
                m_Bitmap = bm
            End Sub
            Public Sub LockBitmap() ' Lock the bitmap's data.
                Dim bounds As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, m_Bitmap.Width, m_Bitmap.Height)
                m_BitmapData = m_Bitmap.LockBits(bounds, Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
                RowSizeBytes = m_BitmapData.Stride
                total_size = m_BitmapData.Stride * m_BitmapData.Height ' Allocate room for the data.
                ReDim ImageBytes(total_size)
                Marshal.Copy(m_BitmapData.Scan0, ImageBytes, 0, total_size) ' Copy the data into the ImageBytes array.
            End Sub
            Public Sub UnlockBitmap() ' Copy the data back into the bitmap
                Dim total_size As Integer = m_BitmapData.Stride * m_BitmapData.Height
                Marshal.Copy(ImageBytes, 0, m_BitmapData.Scan0, total_size)
                m_Bitmap.UnlockBits(m_BitmapData) ' Unlock the bitmap.
                ImageBytes = Nothing ' Release resources.
                m_BitmapData = Nothing ' Release resources.
            End Sub
        End Class
```

Section2: Sub method

```
 Private Sub PixelBasedCorrections(ByRef m_bitmap As Bitmap)
            Dim bm_bytes As New BitmapBytesRGB32(m_bitmap)

            '1
            bm_bytes.LockBitmap()
            For Xcount = 1 To m_bitmap.Width - 2
                For Ycount = 0 To m_bitmap.Height - 1
                    Dim pixPosition1 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition2 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + ((Xcount - 1) * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition3 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + ((Xcount + 1) * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim color1 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1))
                    Dim color2 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2))
                    Dim color3 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3))
                    If color1.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color1.ToArgb <> color2.ToArgb AndAlso
                        color2.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color3.ToArgb = Color.Black.ToArgb Then
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 1)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 2)
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            '2
            For Xcount = 2 To m_bitmap.Width - 3
                For Ycount = 0 To m_bitmap.Height - 1
                    Dim pixPosition1 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition2 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + ((Xcount - 1) * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition3 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + ((Xcount + 2) * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition4 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + ((Xcount - 2) * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim color1 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1))
                    Dim color2 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2))
                    Dim color3 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3))
                    Dim color4 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4))
                    If color1.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color1.ToArgb <> color2.ToArgb AndAlso
                        color2.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color3.ToArgb = Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso
                        color4.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb Then 'xx
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4 + 1)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4 + 2)
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            '3
            For Xcount = 1 To m_bitmap.Width - 2
                For Ycount = 0 To m_bitmap.Height - 1
                    Dim pixPosition1 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition2 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + ((Xcount + 1) * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition3 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + ((Xcount - 1) * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim color1 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1))
                    Dim color2 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2))
                    Dim color3 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3))
                    If color1.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color1.ToArgb <> color2.ToArgb AndAlso
                        color2.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color3.ToArgb = Color.Black.ToArgb Then
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 1)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 2)
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            '4
            For Xcount = 2 To m_bitmap.Width - 3
                For Ycount = 0 To m_bitmap.Height - 1
                    Dim pixPosition1 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition2 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + ((Xcount + 1) * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition3 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + ((Xcount - 2) * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition4 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + ((Xcount + 2) * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim color1 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1))
                    Dim color2 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2))
                    Dim color3 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3))
                    Dim color4 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4))
                    If color1.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color1.ToArgb <> color2.ToArgb AndAlso
                        color2.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color3.ToArgb = Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso
                        color4.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb Then 'xx
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4 + 1)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4 + 2)
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            '5
            For Xcount = 1 To m_bitmap.Width - 2
                For Ycount = 0 To m_bitmap.Height - 1
                    Dim pixPosition1 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition2 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + ((Xcount + 1) * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition3 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + ((Xcount - 1) * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim color1 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1))
                    Dim color2 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2))
                    Dim color3 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3))
                    If color1.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color1.ToArgb <> color2.ToArgb AndAlso
                        color2.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color3.ToArgb = Color.Black.ToArgb Then
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 1)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 2)
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            '6
            For Xcount = 0 To m_bitmap.Width - 1
                For Ycount = 1 To m_bitmap.Height - 2
                    Dim pixPosition1 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition2 As Integer = ((Ycount - 1) * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition3 As Integer = ((Ycount + 1) * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim color1 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1))
                    Dim color2 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2))
                    Dim color3 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3))
                    If color1.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color1.ToArgb <> color2.ToArgb AndAlso
                        color2.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color3.ToArgb = Color.Black.ToArgb Then
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 1)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 2)
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            '7
            For Xcount = 0 To m_bitmap.Width - 1
                For Ycount = 1 To m_bitmap.Height - 2
                    Dim pixPosition1 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition2 As Integer = ((Ycount + 1) * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition3 As Integer = ((Ycount - 1) * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim color1 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1))
                    Dim color2 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2))
                    Dim color3 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3))
                    If color1.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color1.ToArgb <> color2.ToArgb AndAlso
                        color2.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color3.ToArgb = Color.Black.ToArgb Then
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 1)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 2)
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            '8
            For Xcount = 2 To m_bitmap.Width - 3
                For Ycount = 0 To m_bitmap.Height - 1
                    Dim pixPosition1 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition2 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + ((Xcount + 1) * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition3 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + ((Xcount - 1) * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition4 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + ((Xcount + 2) * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition5 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + ((Xcount - 2) * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim color1 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1))
                    Dim color2 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2))
                    Dim color3 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3))
                    Dim color4 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4))
                    Dim color5 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition5 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition5 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition5))
                    If color1.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color1.ToArgb <> color2.ToArgb AndAlso
                        color2.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color2.ToArgb = color3.ToArgb AndAlso
                        color4.ToArgb = color3.ToArgb AndAlso color5.ToArgb = color3.ToArgb Then
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 1)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 2)
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            '9
            For Xcount = 0 To m_bitmap.Width - 1
                For Ycount = 2 To m_bitmap.Height - 3
                    Dim pixPosition1 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition2 As Integer = ((Ycount + 1) * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition3 As Integer = ((Ycount - 1) * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition4 As Integer = ((Ycount + 2) * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim pixPosition5 As Integer = ((Ycount - 2) * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
                    Dim color1 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1))
                    Dim color2 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition2))
                    Dim color3 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3))
                    Dim color4 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition4))
                    Dim color5 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition5 + 2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition5 + 1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition5))
                    If color1.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color1.ToArgb <> color2.ToArgb AndAlso
                        color2.ToArgb <> Color.Black.ToArgb AndAlso color2.ToArgb = color3.ToArgb AndAlso
                        color4.ToArgb = color3.ToArgb AndAlso color5.ToArgb = color3.ToArgb Then
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 1) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 1)
                        bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition1 + 2) = bm_bytes.ImageBytes(pixPosition3 + 2)
                    End If
                Next
            Next

' MORE CODE IN THE SAME VEIN.......

 bm_bytes.UnlockBitmap()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace lines like

```
Dim pixPosition1 As Integer = (Ycount * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (Xcount * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
```

with

```
Dim pixPosition1 As Integer = calcPixelPos(Ycount,0,xCount,0)
Dim color` as Color = CalcColor(pixPosition1,1,2)
```

And add functions that take the differences in each line as parameters - like this:-

```
Private Function calcPixelpos(pYcount As Integer, pYoffset As Integer, pXcount As Integer, pXoffeset As Integer) As Integer
    Return (pYcount + pYoffset * bm_bytes.RowSizeBytes) + (pXcount + pXoffeset * BitmapBytesRGB32.bytesPerPixel)
End Function

Private Function CalcColor(mPxPos As Integer, mOffset1 As Integer, mOffset2 As Integer) As Color
    Return Color.FromArgb(255, bm_bytes.ImageBytes(mPxPos + mOffset1), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(mPxPos + mOffset2), bm_bytes.ImageBytes(mPxPos))
End Function
```

Although you would still need to do some copying and pasting, it would reduce the time needed to edit each paste as all the differences are much closer together. Also you could apply the same kind of ideas to the three lines within each color checking If .. Endif Statement